# Different values of Numpy.var() and Pandas.var()

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scikit-learn, statistics

I am learning a bit about Standard Scaler in datasets. I am noticing a strange behavior which I think might be a syntax or logical error in my code, but can anyone correct me.

As we know that when we do `StandardScaler`, we have a `std` of 1 and `mean` of 0 as `Var = Stdev^2`.

Now when I used this in my code with `sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler`, after using `fit_transform`, the variance was `1`. But when I changed the value in original data frame, It was 1.5 for both rows. Can I know why is it and how to make it 1 using `StandardScaler`. Thanks.

Here is my dataset

```
    Country GDP Area    Continent
0   India   2.79    3.287   Asia
1   USA    20.54    9.840   North America
2   China   13.61   9.590   Asia
```

and here is my code

```py
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

ss = StandardScaler()

var =  ss.fit_transform(catDf.iloc[:,1:-1]).var() #This variance is equal to 1

catDf.iloc[:,1:-1] = ss.fit_transform(catDf.iloc[:,1:-1]) 

print("Variance in Numpy array", var) # Approx 1
print("Variance in Data Frame", catDf.var())# 1.5 for both numerical columns
```

Hopefully, you got what I want to say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is due to using different degrees of freedom. The scikit-learn docs state that they use the **biased** estimator or sample variance:

> We use a biased estimator for the standard deviation, equivalent to numpy.std(x, ddof=0). Note that the choice of ddof is unlikely to affect model performance.

On the other hand, `DataFrame.var` is by default the **unbiased** estimator

> Return unbiased variance over requested axis. Normalized by N-1 by default. This can be changed using the ddof argument

With only 3 points, the difference between dividing by 3 or 2 would lead to a 1.5x difference (exactly what you see). Remedy this by using `ddof=0` for `DataFrame.var()`

```
print(catDf.var(ddof=0))
#GDP     1.0
#Area    1.0
```